# Firefox shows different values from what I see from Firebug

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am not sure if it's a bug or something else, but it looks so strange that I am totally confused.

Please see the image below, the title of the note `#note_title` has value `3333` as in Firebug, but it is shown `44444` in the webpage, and in the console, from jQuery, the value of the title is also `44444`, Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value *attribute* specifies the *default* value.

The value *property* (which `val()` accesses) and the UI show the *current* value.